# Does the question I asked belong here, or is it better on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, stackoverflow

I've asked the following question, and want to get the most exposure for it possible.

Obviously, posting on SO would probably attract more views, but is OK for me to post such a question there, or should the question remain where it is (here)?

[Which command line text editor has the closest keybindings to Notepadd++, Gedit, or Kate (or any modern CUA style editor)?](https://superuser.com/questions/505457/which-command-line-text-editor-has-the-closest-keybindings-to-notepadd-gedit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stackoverflow is for programming issues. One thing to remember though is that questions asking for product recommendations usually get closed, simply because they're off topic, too localized and not constructive.
Part of the other SE etiquette is to not cross posts items across sites.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, given the FAQ & rules of Super User, this is on-topic, given the use of the general "modern" editor.  Personally, I take this to mean configurable, which would likely indicate it has a set of "modern"-esque key bindings (esp. the reference to Common User Access [[CUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access)]).

And really, if anyone can find a CLI-based editor which supports custom bindings, it would surely solve the OP's problem.

---

As a final note, I would try to modify your question to be more neutral in the context I've indicated above.  It's fine to give examples of software that's similar, but I don't think it's helpful to indicate specifics in the title.